# How condition for existence of Fourier transform is valid?

Tags: fft, signal-analysis, fourier-transform, transform, dtft

The condition for Discrete time Fourier transform to exist for function $f(n)$ is given as

$$\sum_{-\infty}^\infty |f(n)|  < \infty.$$

In case of continuous Fourier transform the difference is summation is replaced by integration in the above equation

It looks something
strange for me because on left side we are
taking the signal within 1. **infinity
limits**. Also,2. it is again of **summation type** and **we are expecting right side to be less than infinity**. How is it possible?

Let us take two  examples

> 1. Suppose there is unit step signal $u(n)$
>      with constant unity magnitude
>      ranging from o to $\infty$ .then we
>      can clearly see by putting value
>      in the above formula

L.H.S=1+1+1+......upto ${\infty}$
So R.H.S. =$\infty$

So can I say that DTFT of unit step signal doesn't exist?

> 2. Similarly, if I represent the  power signal like $cos(wn)$  using the exponential terms and compute it's value from the formula of condition of existence ,it will come out to be
>      $\infty$ .

So can I say that DTFT of power signal like 
 $cos(wn)$ doesn't exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in Batman's answer, the condition of the sequence being absolutely summable is only sufficient but not necessary. The Fourier transform can be extended to $\ell_2$ sequences, i.e. sequences for which

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}|f[n]|^2<\infty$$

is satisfied. A further generalization is possible if you allow distributions and their derivatives (such as the Dirac delta function) as Fourier transforms. Then also sequences with polynomial growth have a Fourier transform in that generalized sense. Just sequences with exponential growth have no Fourier transform. However, they can be handled by the $\mathcal{Z}$-transform. Note that everything said above also holds for continuous-time functions (if your replace "$\mathcal{Z}$-transform" by "Laplace transform").

Sequences with a constant amplitude (such as the step function or a sinusoid) will have a Dirac delta in their Fourier transform. Sequences with a linear growth will have the (generalized) derivative of a Dirac delta in their Fourier transform, etc.

And as for your question how it is possible for a sum over infinitely many elements to be finite, your should as a first basic example read up on the [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Geometric_series).

**EDIT:**

So if we allow a Dirac delta impulse as a Fourier transform, we can ask what the corresponding time function would be. By taking the inverse Fourier transform of a shifted Dirac delta impulse $\delta(\omega-\omega_0)$ we get

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(\omega-\omega_0)e^{j\omega t}d\omega=\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{j\omega_0t}$$

which follows from the [sifting property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Translation) of the Dirac delta impulse. So we now have the Fourier transform pair

$$e^{j\omega_0t}\Longleftrightarrow2\pi\delta(\omega-\omega_0)$$

from which the transforms of $\cos(\omega_0t)$ and $\sin(\omega_0t)$ follow directly by rewriting these functions as $\cos(\omega_0t)=\frac12(e^{j\omega_0t}+e^{-j\omega_0t})$ and $\sin(\omega_0t)=\frac{1}{2j}(e^{j\omega_0t}-e^{-j\omega_0t})$.

Comment: Matt L. sir, I want to ask you few things related to your answer. 

1. I can understand that in $e^{-jwn}$ for positive values of **n**, as it tends to $\infty$ the whole exponential term tends to 0 . But on negative axis,for negative values of **n**, the exponential term will keep on increasing in exponentially. So within the range from $-\infty$ to $o$ ,how could you calculate DTFT of  $cos(wn)$ function? 


2. How would you calculate DTFT of unit step function using Dirac delta ?

Comment: @devraj: The complex exponential will not increase in magnitude, neither for positive nor for negative $n$ because $|e^{-j\omega n}|=1$ always holds. The reason is the imaginary unit $j$ in the exponent. The computation of the Fourier transform of the unit step or of a sinusoid can probably be found on the internet, but you could also ask another question as it can't be treated properly in a comment.

Comment: sir, I asked you the 1st query in the comment ,which is about DTFT formula . there is no **mod** of exponential term. there's exponential term . so for the negative side of DTFT formula ,it will be exponentially increasing.

Comment: can you add mathematical computations for understanding in your answer?

Comment: @devraj: You are wrong, the term $e^{-j\omega n}$ will NOT increase in magnitude for real-valued $n$ and $\omega$. It is a *complex* exponential. Please re-visit [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula). And I'm not sure what kind of mathematical computations would aid your understanding.

Comment: sir, in the exponential function $e^{-jwn}$ ,on positive x axis values of $n$ the graph would be exponentially decreasing and exponentially increasing for negative axis for negative values of $n$

Comment: 2.also, can u compute the DTFT of $cos(wn)$ mathematically in your answer box so that my confusion will get clear.

Comment: @devraj: I'm sorry but it appears that you don't understand what $e^{-j\omega t}$ means. Despite my efforts to explain it to you, you keep claiming that it increases or decreases, which is wrong. It would help if you tried to understand the difference between the functions $e^{-jx}$ and $e^{-x}$. If you don't understand this, you can never understand the Fourier transform.

Comment: sir, let me clear you what I know 1. $$e^{-jx}=cos(x)-jsin(x)$$ . OK. then   $|e^{-jx}|$ =1 . and $|e^{-x}|$=$e^{-x}$

Comment: @devraj: OK, so do you see now the fallacy of your statement that the complex exponential $e^{-j\omega n}$ increases exponentially for negative values of $n$ (and in this way makes convergence of the DTFT impossible)?

Comment: @devraj: I've added an explanation concerning the Fourier transform of $\cos(\omega_0 t)$ to my answer.

Comment: OK .agreed. now let us write 


$$cos(wn)=(e^{jwn}+e^{-jwn})/2$$

OK. now, let us neglect any one term of exponential for a moment. OK. then 

$$\sum_{-\infty}^\infty |e^{jwn}|  .$$

OK. then I will solve the above expression as

1+1+1+1........up to $\infty$

OK. so I can say that sum of **infinite** number of 1's is equal to $\infty$. is it right ,sir?

Comment: sir,I have one doubt. can we compute Fourier transform of ramp function?

Comment: @devraj: Yes, we can! As I wrote in my answer, the Fourier transform will include the derivative of the Dirac impulse.

Comment: @devraj: Please re-read my answer, it's all there. I don't want to repeat everything in comments.

Answer (score 2):

the cosine transform can serve as an example to show that the sum is not infinite, if not rather a distribution, in the case of cosine eg are distributions deltas of Dirac spaced periodically in the frequency domain, likewise a train of Kronecker deltas (the Kronecker delta function is analogous to the Dirac delta in the discrete domain and one of its uses is to model the sampling of a signal) or sin(w0n) have transformed that are frequency distributions, I'll show you the images the case of cos(w0n) eg. On the other hand, the transform of the pulse heviside function is still a mystery to me.

[image: Houston commercial photography]

[image: Houston commercial photography]

Comment: What the heck is **constubre**??

Comment: @jojek: I guess it's an unsuccessful translation of a Spanish word for "customary".

Comment: @Esteban sir, I didn't get satisfactory answer for my question from your answer.

Comment: please wait for me, I'm new and do not know how to write formulas in this forum, but I will send a picture where we perform discrete cosine transform, what happens is that the tables showing the books are usually given for a period of frequency between - pi and pi, remember, the Fourier transform of a discrete signal is a periodic function in frecuenci, whose period is 2pi as discrete frequency signals have maxim 1/2, that is why the transformed formulas usually Formulas are given between -pi and pi as f = w / (pi)

Comment: ie the minimum frequency f is -1/2 and the maximum is at the other end bone w=pi which is f = 1/2, do not give full fomula that is periodic and only give you the exprecion for a period, that is why people tend to think that the expression is finite when actually are seeing a period, in a moment upload developing transform cos (w0n) so you understand what I mean, otherwise I am Colombian and use google translator is not that much English, so please try to understand me.

Comment: upload the pictures and I hope you get an idea of why some transforms are a bit rare, ie it seems that the result of doing the sum is infinite but it is not, remember the duality theorem for example, for continuous functions without that theorem transform the sine or cosine could not be done, that is if you can only it is an integral involving the complex domain and this makes the way they operate is different, this identity is very useful to handle this such situations:   https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/f/8/c/f8c9abd61b0587f5b6b48360f3baca3c.png

Answer (score 1):

It's sufficient for a function to be in $L^1$ (i.e. $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f|< \infty$) or $L^2$  (i.e. $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f|^2 < \infty$) to have the Fourier transform exist, but not necessary.

An example where a Fourier transform exists but the function is not in $L^1$ or $L^2$ is the complex sinusoids $e^{j \omega_0 t}$ (which has the Fourier transform being given as the distribution $\delta(\omega - \omega_0)$). Since you can write cosine as a sum of two complex sinusoids, you get the existence of its Fourier transform that way.

As for the unit step, it requires some finesse so see [these notes](http://web.stanford.edu/class/ee102/lectures/fourtran).

Comment: sir,the PDF u suggested doesn't give me proper **step wise** calculations for both unit step and cosine functions.

Comment: can you add mathematical calculations in your answer ?

Comment: Figure out the cosine case on your own by writing $\cos x = \frac{e^{j x}+e^{-j x}}{2}$, plug in $x = \omega t$ and using linearity of the FT. As for the unit step, more details are [here](https://www.cs.uaf.edu/~bueler/M611heaviside.pdf). To make the argument more precise, you need to know some things about distributions, which would be better suited to math.SE.

Comment: sir,in the DTFT formula, the summation is from $-{\infty}$ to $+{\infty}$ .so for periodic signal like $cos(wn)$ which is present for **infinite** interval, how could you compute its DTFT ? specially on the negative  axis I.e. from 0 to $-\infty$ ?

Comment: I suggest you look at the definition of the DTFT, and review your calc 1 course materials. Note that $|e^{j \omega n}| = 1$.

Comment: sir,I agree that $$|e{^jwn}| =1$$. but will you check my last comment at the Matt sir's answer ?

Comment: It sounds like you don't know what the words "sufficient" and "necessary" mean. See this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necessity_and_sufficiency). The condition you have $\sum_i |x[i]| < \infty$ is violated by many things which have Fourier transforms. This is fine, because it is sufficient but not necessary. Also, stop using sir in each response; it's weird.

Comment: OK
but can you give me any example of which we can't compute its Fourier transform transform?

Comment: $e^{t^2}$ is one. Lots of things with bad tails will not work.